# marmalade SDK and integration new libraries in that

Tags: ios

I am new to the marmalade SDK.
I have custom Library of an iOS feature and i want to integrate that library with the marmalade SDK is there any way to add custom Libraries in the default marmalade SDK ?
I should convert my objective C code to the marmalade SDK's compatible language or it can be generate automatically as per working of marmalade juice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate marmalade follow marmalade tutorial. and yes you will have to convert code.